# How to control grouped data after array.prototype.reduce()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, grouping

I've been trying to group ajax data with below code.

```
$.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               contentType: 'application/json',
               url: 'Question.aspx/Areas',
               data: '{}',
               success: function (result) {
                   var data=(result.d).reduce(function (das, current) {
                       das[current.parent] = das[current.parent] || [];
                       das[current.parent].push(current);
                       return das;
                   });

                   console.log(data, {});
                   }
```

Array has parents and areas. I want to group them on parent. Please check out the screen shot for problem.

[image: Console log]

Result seems good except that:**there are 1 more area and 1 more parent in result.** I don't know why it happens. Also i don't know how to use that child data(areas). I want to list them group by group. I need a $each loop like

```
$.each(data, function (parent, child) {

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to add second param (initial value) to `{}` so the object with parents will be empty - here is codepen http://codepen.io/kejt/pen/wgVggg?editors=1012

Comment: @Kejt Yes it works as i want now, thank you :)

Comment: no prob, good luck :D @Furkan Ayik

Comment: @Kejt Hi, i know you've already helped me about this question but i have another question now and my searches didn't help so much. So i hope it's ok i'm gonna ask some help again. I always use $.each for getting data from this kind parented array and i can handle it. But now i want to get it with index. For example (in your codepen) How can i get Stephanie in John with index?
Somethink like;
console.log(grouped[0][0]); or
console.log(grouped[0].name);

Comment: @Kejt I think i'm gonna get parents first, then i'll use like var data=grouped.parent[index].name . If you know better short way let me know :)